# Host and port to use to list a directory in hdfs

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform

First of all, I'm using HortonWorks Sandbox as Hadoop dist, with no custom configuration at all.

Once connected on the sandbox, I'm able to list files of a HDFS directory doing :

`[root@sandbox ~]# hadoop fs -ls hdfs:///user/guest`

but if I try to specify a host and port I get only errors :

`[root@sandbox ~]# hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:8020/user/guest
ls: Call From sandbox.hortonworks.com/10.0.2.15 to localhost:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connexion refusée; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused`

`[root@sandbox ~]# hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000/user/guest
ls: Call From sandbox.hortonworks.com/10.0.2.15 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connexion refusée; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused`

Once I know the correct host and port to use, I'll be able to use them in my Java call :

`Path pt = new Path("hdfs://host:port/user/guest/test-text-file.txt");`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the value of property `fs.defaultFS` in `core-site.xml` this contains the ip-address/hostname and port on which NameNode daemon should bind to when it start's up.

I see that you are using hortonworks sandbox, here is the property in `core-site.xml` and its located in `/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml`

```
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020</value>
</property>
```

So, you could try something like this:

```
hadoop fs -ls hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/guest
```

Or you could also replace the ip address of `sandbox.hortonworks.com` from its respective entry in `/etc/hosts`, on my vm which looks something like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
192.168.1.3 sandbox.hortonworks.com sandbox
```

So, I could try this as well:

```
hadoop fs -ls hdfs://192.168.1.3:8020/user/guest
```

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer. Too bad the tutorial talks about port 9000 or "localhost:8020" which doesnt work (http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/using-commandline-manage-files-hdfs/)